# Detecting failure at runtime?

Tags: erlang

1) Is there a way to automatically detect when a node fails, from another node?

2) Is there a way to automatically re-start the node which just crashed?

Regarding my second question, I have googled about and I cannot see to find any mention to creating nodes from code/at runtime.

I understand you can do this with processes- creating processes at runtime is trivial and if you want to know when they crash you can create them from a supervisor etc- but I cant find anything relating to node detection/creation.

Need this for a client who wish to design a smaller version of Amazon EDS, but I cannot imagine Amazon manually restarting nodes if they go down!

Comment: you can start nodes at run time by executing `net_kernel:start/1`: `net_kernel:start([NodeName,shortnames])` or `net_kernel:start([NodeName,longnames])`. read more here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#start-1   . You can even try it in your erlang shell and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `net_kernel:monitor_nodes(true, [{node_type, visible}])` to monitor all visible nodes from inside your erlang application. From [man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#monitor_nodes-2):

> The calling process subscribes or unsubscribes to node status change
>   messages. A nodeup message is delivered to all subscribing process
>   when a new node is connected, and a nodedown message is delivered when
>   a node is disconnected.

I don't see any straight forward method (from inside your process which receives `nodedown` message) using which you can start a node on remote machine. You will probably need to write a small module which do this for you automatically.

Comment: you can start nodes at run time by executing `net_kernel:start/1`: `net_kernel:start([NodeName,shortnames])` or `net_kernel:start([NodeName,longnames])`. read more here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#start-1   . You can even try it in your erlang shell and see.